# Столкновение круга с прямоугольником

Tags: javascript, canvas, коллизии, прямоугольники, обработка-столкновений

Необходима небольшая помощь в коде. У меня имеется формула определения столкновения круга и прямоугольника, другими словами проверка коллизии:

```js
rect.x < ball.x + ball.radius &&
rect.x + rect.weight > ball.x - ball.radius &&
rect.y < ball.y + ball.radius &&
rect.height + rect.y > ball.y - ball.radius
```

Тут неважно какие размеры фигуры, столкновение определяется успешно что по оси Х, что по оси Y. Столкновение так же определяется и при столкновении круга с углом прямоугольника, но, к сожалению, оно происходит слишком рано, т.е. когда круг еще даже не дотронулся до угла, он считает, что столкновение есть.
Каким образом можно улучшить этот код, чтобы он идеально определял точное столкновение круга и угла прямоугольника?
Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Наверное не шар, а круг имеется ввиду?

Comment: Да, точнее круг, немного не точно написал.

Answer (score 4):

Метод взят [из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection#sphere_vs._aabb)

Суть алгоритма в том, чтобы найти ближайшую к центру круга точку прямоугольника и посмотреть насколько она далеко от центра круга. Если расстояние окажется меньше чем радиус круга, то значит они пересекаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная функция:

```js
function checkCollisionCircleWithRect(circle, rect) {
  const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
  const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));

  // Измеряем расстояние от найденной точки до центра круга
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    (x - circle.x) ** 2 +
    (y - circle.y) ** 2
  );

  const isCollision = distance < circle.radius;
  
  if (isCollision) console.log('Collision');
}
```

Рабочий код (круг нужно/можно двигать мышкой и лучше открыть на всю страницу):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Circle {
  x;
  y;
  radius;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  move(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
    this.path2D.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

class Rect {
  x;
  y;
  height;
  width;
  maxX;
  minX;
  maxY;
  minY;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, height, width, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.maxX = x + width;
    this.minX = x;
    this.maxY = y + height;
    this.minY = y;    
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
        this.path2D.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

const figures = [
  new Circle(320, 200, 50, 'red'),
  new Rect(100, 100, 100, 150, 'blue')
];

function updateFrame() {
  // ОЧИСТКА КАНВАСА
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // РИСУЕМ ОБЪЕКТЫ
  figures.forEach(figure => {
    figure.draw();
  });
  
  checkCollisionCircleWithRect(figures[0], figures[1]);
}

function checkCollisionCircleWithRect(circle, rect) {
  const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
  const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));

  // Измеряем расстояние от найденной точки до центра круга
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    (x - circle.x) ** 2 +
    (y - circle.y) ** 2
  );

  const isCollision = distance < circle.radius;
  
  if (isCollision) console.log('Collision');
}

let startX = null;
let startY = null;
let obj = null;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  
  obj = figures[0];
  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (obj === null) return;
  
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const diffX = x - startX;
  const diffY = y - startY;

  obj.move(obj.x + diffX, obj.y + diffY);

  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  obj = null;
});

// НЕ ОБРАЩАЙТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ НА ТО ЧТО НИЖЕ
// ЭТО ПРОСТО НАСТРОЙКА ИГРОВОГО ЦИКЛА
const targetFPS = 60;
const timeInterval = Math.floor(1000 / 60 * (60 / targetFPS));
let previousFrameTime = performance.now();

(function gameLoop(currentFrameTime = performance.now()) {

    requestAnimationFrame((timeStamp) => gameLoop(timeStamp));

    if (currentFrameTime - previousFrameTime < timeInterval) return;

    previousFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

    updateFrame();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

##### Спасибо [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) за хорошее [замечание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482959/js-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0#comment2657146_1482964)

Действительно, у нас код для обнаружения столкновения вызывается в каждои кадре и чем меньше у нас будет вычислений, тем лучше. Предлагается вместо того чтобы каждый раз вычислять квадратный корень для вычисления расстояния, заранее хранить значение радиуса круга в квадрате. Но эта оптимизация будет иметь смысл, если радиус круга не будет меняться. Если же радиус будет меняться, то предлагается вычислять квадрат радиуса вместо квадратного корня, т.к. [это быстрее](https://jsben.ch/6k3hd)

Значит при инициализации круга, сразу в конструкторе можно это запомнить в отдельном поле и потом использовать где нужно. Тогда общий основная функция будет выглядеть так:

```js
function checkCollisionCircleWithRect(circle, rect) {
  const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
  const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));

  // Измеряем расстояние от найденной точки до центра круга
  const distanceSquare = (x - circle.x) ** 2 + (y - circle.y) ** 2;

  const isCollision = distanceSquare < circle.radiusSquare;
  
  if (isCollision) console.log('Collision');
}
```

Рабочий код (круг нужно/можно двигать мышкой и лучше открыть на всю страницу):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Circle {
  x;
  y;
  radius;
  radiusSquare;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.radiusSquare = radius * radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  move(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
    this.path2D.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

class Rect {
  x;
  y;
  height;
  width;
  maxX;
  minX;
  maxY;
  minY;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, height, width, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.maxX = x + width;
    this.minX = x;
    this.maxY = y + height;
    this.minY = y;    
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
        this.path2D.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

const figures = [
  new Circle(320, 200, 50, 'red'),
  new Rect(100, 100, 100, 150, 'blue')
];

function updateFrame() {
  // ОЧИСТКА КАНВАСА
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // РИСУЕМ ОБЪЕКТЫ
  figures.forEach(figure => {
    figure.draw();
  });
  
  checkCollisionCircleWithRect(figures[0], figures[1]);
}

function checkCollisionCircleWithRect(circle, rect) {
  const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
  const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));

  const distanceSquare = (x - circle.x) ** 2 + (y - circle.y) ** 2;
  
  const isCollision = distanceSquare < circle.radiusSquare;
  
  if (isCollision) console.log('Collision');
}

let startX = null;
let startY = null;
let obj = null;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  
  obj = figures[0];
  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (obj === null) return;
  
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const diffX = x - startX;
  const diffY = y - startY;

  obj.move(obj.x + diffX, obj.y + diffY);

  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  obj = null;
});

// НЕ ОБРАЩАЙТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ НА ТО ЧТО НИЖЕ
// ЭТО ПРОСТО НАСТРОЙКА ИГРОВОГО ЦИКЛА
const targetFPS = 60;
const timeInterval = Math.floor(1000 / 60 * (60 / targetFPS));
let previousFrameTime = performance.now();

(function gameLoop(currentFrameTime = performance.now()) {

    requestAnimationFrame((timeStamp) => gameLoop(timeStamp));

    if (currentFrameTime - previousFrameTime < timeInterval) return;

    previousFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

    updateFrame();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Алгоритм выше написан для общего случая, если вам надо всё самим вычислять через формулы. Учитвая что вы работаете с `canvas`-ом в `JS`, то в основной функции вместо подсчёта расстояния можно использовать [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) для того чтобы выяснить находится ли нужная нам точка внутри круга или нет

Рабочий код (круг нужно/можно двигать мышкой и лучше открыть на всю страницу):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Circle {
  x;
  y;
  radius;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  move(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
    this.path2D.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

class Rect {
  x;
  y;
  height;
  width;
  maxX;
  minX;
  maxY;
  minY;
  color;
  path2D;
  
  constructor(x, y, height, width, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.maxX = x + width;
    this.minX = x;
    this.maxY = y + height;
    this.minY = y;    
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.path2D = new Path2D();
        this.path2D.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill(this.path2D);
  }
}

const figures = [
  new Circle(320, 200, 50, 'red'),
  new Rect(100, 100, 100, 150, 'blue')
];

function updateFrame() {
  // ОЧИСТКА КАНВАСА
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // РИСУЕМ ОБЪЕКТЫ
  figures.forEach(figure => {
    figure.draw();
  });
  
  checkCollisionCircleWithRect(figures[0], figures[1]);
}

function checkCollisionCircleWithRect(circle, rect) {
  const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
  const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));

  const isCollision = ctx.isPointInPath(circle.path2D, x, y);
  
  if (isCollision) console.log('Collision');
}

let startX = null;
let startY = null;
let obj = null;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  
  obj = figures[0];
  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (obj === null) return;
  
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const diffX = x - startX;
  const diffY = y - startY;

  obj.move(obj.x + diffX, obj.y + diffY);

  startX = x;
  startY = y;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  obj = null;
});

// НЕ ОБРАЩАЙТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ НА ТО ЧТО НИЖЕ
// ЭТО ПРОСТО НАСТРОЙКА ИГРОВОГО ЦИКЛА
const targetFPS = 60;
const timeInterval = Math.floor(1000 / 60 * (60 / targetFPS));
let previousFrameTime = performance.now();

(function gameLoop(currentFrameTime = performance.now()) {

    requestAnimationFrame((timeStamp) => gameLoop(timeStamp));

    if (currentFrameTime - previousFrameTime < timeInterval) return;

    previousFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

    updateFrame();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

##### P.S.

Картинка выше немного неправильно отображает, то как работает алгоритм в `JS`. Проблема в том, что в `canvas`-е в `JS` чем больше `y`, тем он ниже, а по картинке кажется, что чем больше `y`, тем выше `y`. Поэтому в коде у меня `maxY = y + height`, а не просто `y`

Comment: Спасибо за идею решения проблемы, однако я немного не могу понять некоторые строки из главной функции:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->
const x = Math.max(rect.minX, Math.min(circle.x, rect.maxX));
const y = Math.max(rect.minY, Math.min(circle.y, rect.maxY));
<!-- end snippet -->

Что означает rect.minX и ret.maxX? Так же и с Y. 
Можно ли как то преобразовать эти условия с моими данными, т.е. чётко координаты X и Y прямоугольника, круга и его радиуса(которые показаны в самом верху), без лишних данных?

Comment: @Mike, не надо пожалуйста вставлять такой код в комментарий. Это невозможно читать :) Вас попросили дополнить ваш вопрос, а не мой ответ) Ну а на счёт переменных что вы спрашиваете, посмотрите пожалуйста в коде у меня, в класс Rect, там прямо в конструкторе написано что эти переменные

Comment: @Mike Вам стало понятно что значат эти переменные?

Comment: Если метод будет вызываться часто, то можно ещё избавиться от вычисления квадратного корня, `const distance = (x - circle.x)**2+(y-circle.y)**2); const isCollision=distance<circle.radius*circle.radius;`

Comment: @MBo А вычисления кореня намного затратнее чем вычисление квадрата или это из рада микро оптимизаций?

Comment: @EzioMercer Если круг не меняется, квадрат радиуса можно заранее вычислить. На JS - да, скорее всего, разницы особой не будет, на компилируемых языках бывает заметно.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо за замечание, добавил в ответ. Если что-то не так можете спокойно править мой ответ :)